# How can I build regular expression in R?

Tags: r, regex

I have the following dataframe:

```
aa123 aa123.1 aa456 aa456.1
1     2       3     4
```

I want to take only the columns that match a pattern: "aa[numbers].1". 
In other words to extract only the columns that end with ".1".

I have tried to use regular expression pattern for grep and dplyr select/filter + ends_with() with pattern = ".1"

But nothing seems to work, please advise me how can I build such pattern and point me to a guide how in the future to build the pattern I need.

Comment: Try `"\\.1$"` pattern. Or `"^aa\\.\\d+$"`. It is not that clear what the actual requirements are.

Comment: To select all columns that end up with .1.
Please explain your solution, I want to understand it.

Comment: Some useful info here: https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/ . Check PDF "Work with Strings Cheat Sheet" and section "regular expressions".

Comment: @AntoniosK Many thanks I have dig into into it and understood! MANY THANKS!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use a regular expression that matches a dot (`\.`) followed with `1` followed with end of string (`$`).

Use the following regex then:

```
"\\.1$"
```

The dot must be escaped to match a literal dot.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kzRzRF/1).

Comment: But why I need the second \? I mean why \\. instead of \.?

Comment: @Dr.RichardTennen Because to define a single *literal* backslash (=a regex escape symbol), you need to use two consecutive backslash symbols inside an R string literal.